# MySQL. Как преобразовать TEXT или INT в LONGTEXT для SELECT?

Tags: mysql, строки, select, типы, конвертация

В MySQL для `SELECT` есть функция `CAST`, он может конвертировать в `VARCHAR`, а в `LONGTEXT` он конвертировать не может, выдаёт ошибку 1064. А функция `CONVERT ... USING` преобразовывает в текст (строку), но не в `LONGTEXT`

Пример SQL-запроса, который не работает:

```
SELECT `id` AS `post_id`, CAST('content' AS VARCHAR(255)) AS `key`, CAST(`content` AS LONGTEXT) AS `va1ue` FROM `posts`
```

Answer (score 0):

[CAST() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)

> - CHAR[(*N*)] [*charset_info*]
>
> Produces a string with the VARCHAR data type. except that when the expression expr is empty (zero length), the result type is CHAR(0). If the optional length N is given, CHAR(N) causes the cast to use no more than N characters of the argument. No padding occurs for values shorter than N characters. If the optional length N is not given, MySQL calculates the maximum length from the expression. If the supplied or calculated length is greater than an internal threshold, the result type is TEXT. **If the length is still too long, the result type is LONGTEXT**.

Само по себе преобразование именно в тип данных LONGTEXT, даже если таковое бы существовало, совершенно бессмысленно.

Единственная ситуация, когда такое преобразование могло бы иметь смысл - это запрос `CREATE TABLE .. SELECT`. Однако в этом случае гораздо проще задать требуемый тип данных в первой части запроса.